# Obtener valores de un EditText que está dentro de un ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, edittext

Tengo un problema el cual me lleva rompiendo la cabeza unos cuantos días.
Tengo una actividad el cual estoy utilizando un ListView personalizado, dicho ListView tiene un ImageView y un EditText. El problema viene cuando quiero guardar el contenido que se escribe en cada EditText, solamente quiero obtener lo que se escribe, no he encontrado una solución a lo que busco.

Este es el adaptador que tengo en la actividad:

```
class AdaptadorImagenes extends ArrayAdapter<ListaImagenes>{
    AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;

    AdaptadorImagenes(AppCompatActivity context){
        super(context, R.layout.imagenes, Imagenes);
        appCompatActivity = context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = appCompatActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagenes, null);

        ImageView listaimg = item.findViewById(R.id.listaimg);
        EditText listades = item.findViewById(R.id.listades);

        //Bitmap personalizado para mostrar las imámenes con menos resolucion y no alente el celular.
        //La resolución no se baja a la imagen original.
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(DirectorioImagenes + "/" + Imagenes.get(position).getLocalizacion()));
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            int bitmapAncho = 560, bitmapAlto = 360;
            Bitmap bitmapMostrar = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmapAncho, bitmapAlto, false);

            listaimg.setImageBitmap(bitmapMostrar);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listades.setText(Imagenes.get(position).getDescripcion());

        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
}
```

Y por si es necesario el xml para el ListView personalizado junto a la clase:

imagenes.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/listaimg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#565656"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/listades"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Descripción"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
```

ListaImagenes.java:

```
public class ListaImagenes {
private String localizacion;
private String descripcion;

public ListaImagenes(String localizacion, String descripcion){
    this.localizacion = localizacion;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public String getLocalizacion(){
    return localizacion;
}

public String getDescripcion(){
    return descripcion;
}
```

Los datos los guardo en una base de datos, como el nombre de las imagenes ya están declaradas antes de agregar objetos a la ListView no hay problema, pero se declaran con "descripción" siendo nulos.

Necesito una forma de tomar lo escrito en los EditText o de alguna manera actualizar la clase AdaptadorImagenes para que esté guardando lo que se escribe en las EditText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas desplegando en el `EditText` el valor `descripcion`

```
  ...
  EditText listades = item.findViewById(R.id.listades);
  ...
  listades.setText(Imagenes.get(position).getDescripcion());
  ...
```

Por lo tanto si deseas guardar un valor debe existir una forma de agregarlo, por ejemplo un botón, y en tu objeto `ListaImagenes` agregarias un método set para agregar el valor en el objeto.

```
public class ListaImagenes {
...
...
public String getDescripcion(){
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String valor){
    descripcion = valor;
}

}
```

para insertar el valor simplemente llama el método:

```
Imagenes.get(position).setDescripcion(listades.getText().toString());
```

---

Si deseas guardar el valor en tu objeto por ejemplo cuando pierde el foco puedes usar el listener `OnFocusChangeListener`, ejemplo:

```
listades.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {

           //Guarda valor en objeto    
           Imagenes.get(position).setDescripcion(listades.getText().toString());


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: ¿Hay una manera de llamar ese método que menciona al modificar el EditText de la lista?
Es decir, al terminar de escribir que se llame el método, o llamar el método cada vez que se escriba cada dígito en el EditText.

Comment: cada dígito no lo creo conveniente, mejor al terminar de escribir puedes usar OnFocusChangeListener, agrego un ejemplo a mi respuesta.

Comment: Estoy utilizando eso y veo que no realiza nada.
Pero encontré algo y estoy probando utilizar un arreglo (o vector) de EditTexts, y lo que estoy haciendo es que cada vez que ejecuto el adaptador y crea el objeto EditText de la lista, lo declaro en el arreglo.

EditText[] EditTextLista = new EditText[longitud];

¿Lo ve como una buena alternativa?
Más tarde lo seguiré probando.

Comment: Muchas gracias, hasta ahora pude utilizarlo debidamente, a un principio me revolvía porque no sabía donde declarar ese "OnFocusChangeListener", pero ya sé que es dentro del "getView" del adaptador.
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

puedes tratar con esto:

```
class AdaptadorImagenes extends ArrayAdapter<ListaImagenes>{
Listener listener;

AdaptadorImagenes(AppCompatActivity context, Listener listener){
        super(context, R.layout.imagenes, Imagenes);
        appCompatActivity = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = appCompatActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagenes, null);

        ImageView listaimg = item.findViewById(R.id.listaimg);
        EditText listades = item.findViewById(R.id.listades);
        listades.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    listener.onChanged(((EditText)v).getText());
                }
            }
        });

interface Listener{
onChanged(String text);
}
```

en el activity que utilices agrega esto

```
        implements Listener{
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
        AdaptadorImagenes adapter = new AdaptadorImagenes(getContext, this);
    ...
        }

onChanged(String text){
//aqui pones lo que quieras... lo guardas en una lista o lo que busques
}
    }
```

postdata: te recomiendo usar Recyclerview

Comment: Hola Diego, es excelente tener más contribuciones en el sitio, solo recuerda agregar una descripción de lo que realiza el código y de que forma resuelve el problema planteado por el OP, revisa [answer] saludos!

Comment: oh vale disculpa el detalle